# HttpClient call wiht .Net Core 3.1 fails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Error using .Net Core 3.1

```
private static async Task<List<DataModel>> ProcessRepositories()
{
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var stringTask = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
        var response = await stringTask.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<DataModel>>();
        return response;
}
```

Getting error:

> res:
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[cc_test.DataModel],cc_test.Program+d__3]

It working fine using `.Result` (but this will be blocking code)

Comment: Why are you doing static?  Also don't you want `ReadAsStringAsync`?  Wouldn't you want it to deserialize the response?

Comment: It works fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DfcPyC

Comment: Are you using `ReadAsAsync` from "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client"? If so, which version?